# Tomcat disable / destroy or reuse session creation for specific requests

Tags: jsp, tomcat, tomcat7, session-management

## Background

I am using Tomcat to serve a .jsp page that can be called by a load-balancer to determine if a given server hosting an application is online and able to service requests.

The .jsp simply makes a request to the given application and to see if it is able to respond - sending an appropriate response to the load-balancer.

The issue is that each request to this .jsp is creating a session in Tomcat that persists for some time - there can potentially be many load balancers requesting this page causing a build up of sessions consuming resources.

## Question

Am I able to configure Tomcat to do any of the following?

- Not create a session to handle specific requests
- Reuse a single session or already created session to handle specific requests
- Immediately destroy a session that is created for specific requests, or give said session a very small lifetime

By specific requests I mean the .jsp I wish to serve from Tomcat.

I am using Tomcat 7.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: so after some more digging (and reading a question about how tomcat works in more detail), a solution that works for my situation is to call `session.invalidate()` in the .jsp file , which is much simpler than I thought it would be (I am new to tomcat configuration)>

The questions still remains however if there are way to reuse a session or not create one for specific requests that would be greats to see (if it is possible)

Comment: Christopher has given a perfectly valid answer to the letters of your question. I'd like to add the question: Have you identified this extra memory requirement as a problem? This sounds a lot like preliminary optimization to me. While Christopher's answer is simple enough to do, I'd warn to get into the habit of optimizing something that is not proven to be an actual problem. There will most likely be actual bottlenecks that probably are triggered way before an empty session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of options, here.

First, you could simply switch to using a static file instead of a dynamic JSP page. If the server is accepting requests, this will probably work just as well as running a JSP page... unless your JSP probes certain things to ascertain application health.

Another way is to disable session-generation for that JSP. By default, sessions are created when you access a JSP unless you specify otherwise. Here's how to do that:

```
<%@page
  session="false"
  ..
%>
... rest of your page
```

Now your JSP page won't even generate a session, so you don't have to dispose of them or anything like that.

Finally, if you *need* a session in that JSP for some reason, you can indeed use a single session for all clients of a particular type. You can do that using the [CrawlerSessionManagerValve](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/config/valve.html#Crawler_Session_Manager_Valve). Just make sure you set the `crawlerUserAgents` string to match whatever your load-balancer is using for its probes.

Answer (score 0):

How about just lowering the session time out to 1 minute

```
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>1</session-timeout>
</session-config>
```